# dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime after installing Golang

Tags: go, installation

So, I recently downloaded Golang from this link:
https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.2.darwin-amd64.pkg

The installation was completed with no errors, but when I try running `go version`, this happens:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/go/bin/go
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm running Mac OSX version 10.11.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go1.16.2 needs an OS greater than MacOS 10.11.6 "OS X El Capitan" according to the golang download documents.

I installed go1.15.11 successfully on MacOS X version 10.11.6 .